# jQuery how to properly capture radio change

Tags: jquery

I have a simple list of a few radio buttons and just cannot seem to capture. I have tried multiple possible solutions found on SO and youtube, however nothing seems to work.

Here is the the sample HTML:

```
<ul id="shipping_method">
                    <li>
                  <div class="shipping-block"><input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate4" value="flat_rate:4"  class="shipping_method" /><label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate4">
                  <div class="shipping-block-row clearfix">
                  <div class="shipping-radio"></div>
                  <div class="shipping-title">
                  <h3>Delivery 1</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shipping-price">5,00 €</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shipping-description"><p>Description 1</p></div></label>
              </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                  <div class="shipping-block"><input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_local_pickup3" value="local_pickup:3"  class="shipping_method" /><label for="shipping_method_0_local_pickup3">
                  <div class="shipping-block-row clearfix">
                  <div class="shipping-radio"></div>
                  <div class="shipping-title">
                  <h3>Delivery 2</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shipping-price">3,00 €</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shipping-description"><p>Description 2</p></div></label>
                  </div>
                        </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the jQuery (I have tried change, on change etc.):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
      alert(this.value);
  });

});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle with the sample data](https://jsfiddle.net/03ume31j/)

Comment: You forgot to load to jQuery. Indeed, it was simple :)

Comment: Well jQuery is loaded. If I try to alert outside the change function, it does alert a given message.

Comment: Then this fiddle doesn't reproduce the problem. I checked the settings, I realized jQuery isn't loaded. Loaded and started working as should be.

Comment: I have just tested myself and it does work. However, it still does not work on the site..

Comment: Are the radios appended to the DOM dynamically? In that case you need to use event delegation.  Search google for it.

Comment: You could link us to your site if that is possible. You could have other scripts binding itself  to those inputs.

Comment: Alert() is not a JQuery function. So it will work without JQuery. Just check if you have JQuery script. And alert the price like this.   alert($(this).parent().find('.shipping-price').text());

Comment: We already have two answers with output. But still comments are coming :)

Comment: @Qsprec, I guess `$.alert()` would do the trick, then :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone for your answers. It is a WooCommerce project and if I do not load any of the woocommerce js files, it actually works. However, I still need to generic woocommerce scripts to work too...

Answer (score -1):

Here is the updated fiddle.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
      alert(this.value);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="shipping_method">
     <li>
                  <div class="shipping-block"><input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate4" value="flat_rate:4"  class="shipping_method" /><label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate4">
                  <div class="shipping-block-row clearfix">
                  <div class="shipping-radio"></div>
                  <div class="shipping-title">
                  <h3>Delivery 1</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shipping-price">5,00 €</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shipping-description"><p>Description 1</p></div></label>
              </div>
      </li>
      <li>
                  <div class="shipping-block"><input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_local_pickup3" value="local_pickup:3"  class="shipping_method" /><label for="shipping_method_0_local_pickup3">
                  <div class="shipping-block-row clearfix">
                  <div class="shipping-radio"></div>
                  <div class="shipping-title">
                  <h3>Delivery 2</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shipping-price">3,00 €</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shipping-description"><p>Description 2</p></div></label>
                  </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```